# Django installation issues

Tags: django, apache, amazon-ec2

I configured Django and Apache on an ec2 server with a connection to a remote rds server, which is working fine. I can access the ec2 server and the database (via ssh to the ec2 server and then to the rds server), I tried to run a migration with `sudo python manage.py` and it worked; the database shows my tables.

I use a virtual environment with the Python `mod_wsgi` installed which is loaded in the `apache2.conf` and in the `000-default.conf`. I have the wsgi daemon process, and script references.

When I try to run the application through my browser I get a 500 internal server error with the following error message:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
>    Did you install mysqlclient?
>    mod_wsgi (pid=7875): Target WSGI script '/var/www/wuyeguanli/wuyeapp/wuyeapp/wsgi.py'
>    does not contain WSGI application 'application'.

the complete error message:
[image: the complete error message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first time around i installed the python packages in both root and the virtual environment. doing a clean configuration solved the problem.